# foreach with index

Tags: c#, foreach

Is there a C# equivalent of Python's `enumerate()` and Ruby's `each_with_index`?

Comment: If you're using LINQ, there are overrides of the various functions that allow for enumeration. Otherwise, you're usually stuck using a variable that you increment yourself.

Comment: Can we update this question to C# 7.0 where there are tuples now? I wonder how a solution would look using tuples.

Comment: Isn"t that a feature of `foreach` that you can process each element absolute decoupled from its position in the list?

Answer (score 278):

I keep this extension method around for this:

```
public static void Each<T>(this IEnumerable<T> ie, Action<T, int> action)
{
    var i = 0;
    foreach (var e in ie) action(e, i++);
}
```

And use it like so:

```
var strings = new List<string>();
strings.Each((str, n) =>
{
    // hooray
});
```

Or to allow for `break`-like behaviour:

```
public static bool Each<T>(this IEnumerable<T> ie, Func<T, int, bool> action)
{
    int i = 0;
    foreach (T e in ie) if (!action(e, i++)) return false;
    return true;
}

var strings = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" };

bool iteratedAll = strings.Each ((str, n)) =>
{
    if (str == "b") return false;
    return true;
});
```

Comment: you cannot break in this foreach loop.

Comment: That is because it is not a foreach loop.

Comment: @TriQ That's just another reason to prefer it, most of the time. :)

Comment: @TankorSmash exactly what the question asked for

Comment: @DanFinch I wasn't being snarky, I was legitimately looking for an answer.

Comment: What if you were to `return false;` ala jQuery? Obviously the method would have to modified.

Comment: If you need to break, I'd go with David Morton's answer. Clearer to maintainers and probably less noise.

Comment: @TankorSmash It's an "extension method". Look this up. Bit of awesome C# magic.

Comment: It is a nice extension, but it still annoys me that I have to waste time writing it. Someone's philosophy is that `foreach` with `i++` is cleaner and better and more expressive than a `ForEach((item, index) => {})`. Go figure.

Answer (score 260):

You can do the following

```
foreach (var it in someCollection.Select((x, i) => new { Value = x, Index = i }) )
{
   if (it.Index > SomeNumber) //      
}
```

This will create an anonymous type value for every entry in the collection. It will have two properties

- `Value`: with the original value in the collection
- `Index`: with the index within the collection

Comment: Clever, but it's like scratching your left ear with your right hand.  I guess I'll just keep the index myself, so I don't confuse future maintainers.

Comment: A for effort but F for general readability and maintenance.  Sorry.

Comment: @Neil, I'm amazed that people think this is a maintenence problem.  This overload of Select (and other LINQ methods) was provided for the complete purpose of doing operations like this.

Comment: Very clever.  For small n, this would suit the job nicely.  Looks pretty readable to me.

Comment: I see no issues with maintenance.  If a future maintainer is incapable of going to the MSDN documentation and looking up the overloads to the Select method, that is their own problem.  Worried about the variable names?  Just do:  (Value, Index) => select new { Value, Index }  for the lambda.

Comment: I see no maintenance issues other than possibly giving x,i more useful names. They were obviously left vague here to be renamed to something appropriate when the code is inserted in the desired spot. If this type of code is unreadable to you I'd just forgo attempting any truly terse languages such as C++ or F#...

Comment: Compared to PHP's foreach($listvar as $index=>$val) it is clunky, but it's more flexible. Saying this is a maintenance problem is like saying the construct foreach(array_keys($array) as $val) is a maintenance problem...

Comment: This is clearly worse to the classical for loop. Because it's much more noisy. More (curly) brackets. More text to read. Harder to read and understand than the classical for loop by far.

Comment: @Falcon the OP did not ask for the easiest to read solution, they asked for the closest equivalent to a construct from a different language which my answer represents

Comment: There's no point to using a very weird foreach instead of the usual for loop. Everyone that fails to see that's a maintenance issue should read ancient and grammatically correct English; believe me, convention helps. (also: more characters and less performance)

Comment: @Lodewijk Without a backing collection, `IEnumerable<T>.ElementAt(i)` is O(n) (see [Schlemiel the Painter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter%27s_algorithm#Schlemiel_the_Painter.27s_algorithm)).  And what if you have a lazy enumerable that's expensive to evaluate and contains a huge number of records?  With a for loop, you have to wait for `IEnumerable<T>.Count()` to return before you can start processing the records.  A for loop is generally not appropriate for use with `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: I think that's a surprisingly good point, but highly dependent on the situation. I would fully agree with you if it weren't so extremely rare that there isn't O(1) retrieval. I'll add to that that O(n) conversion to O(1) retrieval is still ultimately O(1). And in the normal situation (arrays, for example) foreach creates more assembly code than a normal "for" loop. In those special cases where it is better, do it with a foreach :). It's more functional, too, which is good.

Comment: This can now get a bit shorter when using a C# 7 ValueTuple: `foreach (var (x, i) in someCollection.Select((x, i) => (x, i)) ) { ... }`

Comment: I've been using C# for almost 2 decades and the first time I made use of this was yesterday.  Thanks, Jared.  This will certainly come in handy.

Answer (score 74):

The C# foreach doesn't have a built in index.  You'll need to add an integer outside the foreach loop and increment it each time.

```
int i = -1;
foreach (Widget w in widgets)
{
   i++;
   // do something
}
```

Alternatively, you could use a standard for loop as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < widgets.Length; i++)
{
   w = widgets[i];
   // do something
}
```

Comment: I think you should initialize i to -1 and increment it at the beginning of the loop body to make sure that a "continue" statement doesn't cause problems.

Comment: @DrJokepu why don't simply keep i = 0 and increment it before the closing bracket of the foreach statement? Initializing with something != 0 triggers the attention when you later browse the code...

Comment: worked in javascript

Answer (score 17):

I like being able to use foreach, so I made an extension method and a structure:

```
public struct EnumeratedInstance<T>
{
    public long cnt;
    public T item;
}

public static IEnumerable<EnumeratedInstance<T>> Enumerate<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection)
{
    long counter = 0;
    foreach (var item in collection)
    {
        yield return new EnumeratedInstance<T>
        {
            cnt = counter,
            item = item
        };
        counter++;
    }
}
```

and an example use:

```
foreach (var ii in new string[] { "a", "b", "c" }.Enumerate())
{
    Console.WriteLine(ii.item + ii.cnt);
}
```

One nice thing is that if you are used to the Python syntax, you can still use it:

```
foreach (var ii in Enumerate(new string[] { "a", "b", "c" }))
```

Comment: What part of that last bit looks like Python syntax to you?

Comment: Sorry for necropost. I moddified your function so it looks pretty and more pythonic in use: http://pastebin.com/aExvenyY

Answer (score 16):

Aside from the LINQ answers already given, I have a ["SmartEnumerable"](https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/miscutil/usage/smartenumerable.html) class which allows you to get the index and the "first/last"-ness. It's a bit ugly in terms of syntax, but you may find it useful.

We can probably improve the type inference using a static method in a nongeneric type, and implicit typing will help too.

Comment: Great! These small little helper properties (first/last/index) should be included in the standard .net framework!

Comment: It is great, I just dislike its long and non descriptive name

Answer (score 6):

My solution involves a simple Pair class I created for general utility, and which is operationally essentially the same as the framework class KeyValuePair.  Then I created a couple extension functions for IEnumerable called Ordinate (from the set theory term "[ordinal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number)").

These functions will return for each item a Pair object containing the index, and the item itself.

```
public static IEnumerable<Pair<Int32, X>> Ordinate<X>(this IEnumerable<X> lhs)
{
    return lhs.Ordinate(0);
}

public static IEnumerable<Pair<Int32, X>> Ordinate<X>(this IEnumerable<X> lhs, Int32 initial)
{
    Int32 index = initial - 1;

    return lhs.Select(x => new Pair<Int32, X>(++index, x));
}
```

Comment: Note that these days there's a `System.Tuple` for your `Pair`.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is not.

As other people have shown, there are ways to simulate Ruby's behavior. But it is possible to have a type that implements [IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable(VS.71).aspx) that does not expose an index.

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out interesting solution:

```
public class DepthAware<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<T> source;

    public DepthAware(IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        this.source = source;
        this.Depth = 0;
    }

    public int Depth { get; private set; }

    private IEnumerable<T> GetItems()
    {
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            yield return item;
            ++this.Depth;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetItems().GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}

// Generic type leverage and extension invoking
public static class DepthAware
{
    public static DepthAware<T> AsDepthAware<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        return new DepthAware<T>(source);
    }

    public static DepthAware<T> New<T>(IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        return new DepthAware<T>(source);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var chars = new[] {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'}.AsDepthAware();

foreach (var item in chars)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Char: {0}, depth: {1}", item, chars.Depth);
}
```

Comment: Resurrecting a zombie since I just needed this: this will behave confusingly if the enumerable is iterated more than once.

Comment: You are right. If I were to implement this today, I'd definitely go with the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is your collection

```
var values = new[] {6, 2, 8, 45, 9, 3, 0};
```

Make a range of indexes for this collection

```
var indexes = Enumerable.Range(0, values.Length).ToList();
```

Use the range to iterate with index

```
indexes.ForEach(i => values[i] += i);
indexes.ForEach(i => Console.Write("[{0}] = {1}", i, values[i]));
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the class you are using.

Dictionary<(Of <(TKey, TValue>)>) Class For Example Support This

The Dictionary<(Of <(TKey, TValue>)>) generic class provides a mapping from a set of keys to a set of values.

For purposes of enumeration, each item in the dictionary is treated as a KeyValuePair<(Of <(TKey, TValue>)>) structure representing a value and its key. The order in which the items are returned is undefined.

foreach (KeyValuePair kvp in myDictionary) {...}