# LINQ/C#: Where & Foreach using index in a list/array

Tags: c#, linq, foreach, where-clause

I have a list/array and need to process certain elements, but also need the index of the element in the processing.
Example:

```
List Names = john, mary, john, bob, simon
Names.Where(s => s != "mary").Foreach(MyObject.setInfo(s.index, "blah")
```

But cannot use the "index" property with lists, inversely if the names were in an Array I cannot use Foreach...
Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want the index in the original collection or the index in the filtered set?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# foreach with index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/521687/c-sharp-foreach-with-index)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use a simple `for` loop, like this:

```
var someNames = Names.Where(s => s != "mary").ToArray();

for (int i = 0; i < someNames.Length; i++)
    someNames.setInfo(i, "blah");
```

LINQ is not the be-all and end-all of basic loops.

If you *really* want to use LINQ, you need to call `Select`:

```
Names.Where(s => s != "mary").Select((s, i) => new { Index = i, Name = s })
```

Comment: If you're going to recommend a for loop, then I suggest you put the conditions in the for loop as well, instead of using Linq first, then looping through the array.

Answer (score 4):

Yes there is a way without using a loop.

You just need to `.ToList()` your `.Where()` clause

```
Names.Where(s => s != "mary").ToList().Foreach(MyObject.setInfo(s.index, "blah");
```

Answer (score 1):

Foreach perform on each element from the collection.
Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z(v=vs.110).aspx

Below is the sample code for your case

```
List<string> Names = new List<string> { "john", "mary", "john", "bob", "simon" };

int index = 0;

Names.Where(s => s != "mary").ToList().ForEach(x => printItem(index++,x));
```

printItem method

```
public static void printItem(int index, string name){
    Console.WriteLine("Index = {0}, Name is {1}",index,name);
}
```

Output:

> Index = 0, Name is john
>
> Index = 1, Name is john
>
> Index = 2, Name is bob
>
> Index = 3, Name is simon