# Current index of foreach loop

Tags: c#, loops, foreach, indexing

Is there a way to know the current run of a foreach without have to:

```
Int32 i;
foreach
   i++;
```

or is that the best option I got? Also, how can I know the maximum number of items on that loop? What I am trying to do is update a progressbar during a foreach loop on my form.

This is what I have so far:

```
    FileInfo[] directoryFiles = (new DirectoryInfo(folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath)).GetFiles("*.*");
    foreach (FileInfo file in directoryFiles)
    {
        if ((file.Attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) == FileAttributes.Hidden || (file.Attributes & FileAttributes.System) == FileAttributes.System)
            continue;

        backgroundWorkerLoadDir.ReportProgress(i, file.Name);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
    }
```

So it should be like the following, right?

```
   for (Int32 i = 0; i < DirectoryFiles.Length; i++)
   {
       if ((DirectoryFiles[i].Attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) == FileAttributes.Hidden || (DirectoryFiles[i].Attributes & FileAttributes.System) == FileAttributes.System)
           continue;

       backgroundWorkerLoadDir.ReportProgress((i / DirectoryFiles.Length) * 100, DirectoryFiles[i].Name);
       System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
   }
```

Comment: Could you paste your current code, including the declaration for the collection that you're iterating?

Comment: Please post some real code, not pseudo-code.

Comment: what is the type of array /collection u are looping through?

Comment: Looks like what you are after is something like [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate "enumerate") in Python, however there is not a C# equivalent. The other answers given outline your options in C#. **Update** Actually, this is discussed in another post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/521687/c-foreach-with-index

Comment: If i use the For loop, how can i make it doesn't count on the hidden files and system ones? would i need to make another loop to count the number of files 1st?

Comment: what is type of DirectoryFiles?

Comment: Sorry, forgot that, just added it.

Comment: ok so it is an array use for loop as suggested in my answer. DirectoryFiles.Length will count all in array. So u know in advance how many elements are there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [(C#) Get index of current foreach iteration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43021/c-get-index-of-current-foreach-iteration)

Comment: The canonical question is *[How do you get the index of the current iteration of a foreach loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43021)*.

Answer (score 7):

Foreach is a fairly big deal, its underlying plumbing is a very simple forward-only iterator that doesn't require having to know up front how many items are in the collection.  IEnumerator<>.

Which is in general is a rather nasty mismatch with a ProgressBar.  You can only meaningfully update the standard one when you know up front how many items you're iterating.  So you can set its Maximum property.  If *that's* possible then you no doubt have access to a Count property and have an indexer as well.  Which then lets you use a for() statement, problem solved.

But it is pretty common that you have no idea up front how many items there are to iterate.  Typical with dbase queries for example.  Since you can't find out how long it might take to iterate, you've only got one option on the progress bar: Style = Marquee.  The "I'm not dead, I'm working" way of reporting progress.  Problem solved.

Answer (score 6):

Use `for` loop instead of `foreach`. That is better in this situation.

Use it like this:

```
count = DirectoryFiles.Length;
for (int k = 0; k < count; k++)
{
    FileInfo file = DirectoryFiles[k];
    if ((file.Attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) == FileAttributes.Hidden || 
        (file.Attributes & FileAttributes.System) == FileAttributes.System)
    {
        continue;
    }

    backgroundWorkerLoadDir.ReportProgress(i, file.Name);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
}
```

Comment: Sorry to say this, but this doesn't work for `ICollection`. :(

Comment: @Lambert good point. Not sure what OP is trying to loop  through.

Comment: @cody it is a for loop. I think it is more suitable in this situation

Comment: Heh, sorry. I meant to type `foreach` suggesting that you edit your answer to a `for` loop instead. But I apparently made the inverse error that you did. I see you've already fixed it, though, so no matter! +1

Answer (score 2):

No, it is impossible for IEnumerable, because it has not Count/Length property. Moreover, you can easily imagine infinite IEnumerable sequence, like:

```
private readonly Random rand = new Random();
private IEnumerable<int> GetInfiniteRandomSequence() 
{
    while(true)
    {
        yield return rand.Next();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's your best option, because standard `for` loops don't work on `IEnumerable`s that are not indexable. If you need to know the number of items, use the `Count` property; if none is available, then obviously by definition you can't know ahead of time.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.Linq;

for (var i = 0; i < items.Count(); i++)
{
    // Update progress bar here.
}
```

Comment: I added the using directive and changed the Count to a method.  That will work for ICollection containers.

Comment: Now it's only for .NET 3.5+... :) and by the way, that is *very* slow because I don't think the JIT compiler can see far enough to only evaluate items.Count() once, so it'll evaluate it multiple times, resulting in a dramatic speed decrease for some collections. You'd need to cache the variable in the beginning. :)

Comment: Someone once tell me than for loop is always faster than foreach loop? But https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365615/in-net-which-loop-runs-faster-for-or-foreach

Answer (score 1):

The basic principle for this problem is the following:

```
List<string> numbers = new List<string>() { "one", "two", "three" };

foreach (var num in numbers.Select((value, index) => new { value, index }))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Value: {0}, Index: {1}", num.value, num.index);
}
```

This will create a new anonymous type within the foreach loop that contains the `value` and `index` within the num variable.

So to solve the problem provided in the OP:

```
FileInfo[] directoryFiles = (new DirectoryInfo(folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath)).GetFiles("*.*");
foreach (FileInfo file in directoryFiles.Select((value, index) => new {value, index}))
{
    if ((file.Attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) == FileAttributes.Hidden
          ||
        (file.Attributes & FileAttributes.System) == FileAttributes.System)
        continue;

    int progress = (file.index / DirectoryFiles.Length) * 100;

    backgroundWorkerLoadDir.ReportProgress(progress, file.value.Name);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
}
```