# Combine foreach with an index

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# foreach with index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521687/c-sharp-foreach-with-index)

I enjoy working the simplicity of foreach in C#, but I often need an index.  Is there any way to combine these elegantly into one simple structure without doing the following:

```
for(var i = 0; i<items.Count; i++) {
    var item = items[i];
```

Or

```
int i = 0;
foreach(var item in items) {
    i++;
```

I'd imagine something neat like:

```
foreach(var item in items;int index) {
```

Comment: foreach(var item in items){return items.index}.. something like this

Comment: Other than samantic candy, what is the benefit? For Loop is for indexed access and the ForEach for object access - the ForEach does not allow changes to the collection during the loop, whereas the for loop does. What might be a better solution (if it were avaiable) would be a simple variable on the ForEach item to return its index, but I guess that then forces index order on the ForEach.

Comment: Yep, duplicate it seems. What do I do? Delete question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes,

there's a neat extension method that i found here on SO:

[foreach with index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521687/c-sharp-foreach-with-index)

works a bit like this (verbatim from previous answer):

```
public static void Each<T>( this IEnumerable<T> ie, Action<T, int> action )
{
    var i = 0;
    foreach ( var e in ie ) action( e, i++ );
}
```

and is used like:

```
var strings = new List<string>();
strings.Each(( str, n ) =>
{
    // hooray can capture 'n' as well as 'str'
});
```

or:

```
strings.Each((str, n) => Console.WriteLine(str));
```

Comment: Then this is a duplicate question ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/521687/c-sharp-foreach-with-index#answer-521705 will be more convincing solution....