# List<T>.ForEach with index

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I'm trying to find the LINQ equivalent of the following code:

```
NameValueCollection nvc = new NameValueCollection();

List<BusinessLogic.Donation> donations = new List<BusinessLogic.Donation>();
donations.Add(new BusinessLogic.Donation(0, "", "", "");
donations.Add(new BusinessLogic.Donation(0, "", "", "");
donations.Add(new BusinessLogic.Donation(0, "", "", "");

for(var i = 0; i < donations.Count(); i++)
{
    // NOTE: item_number_ + i - I need to be able to do this
    nvc.Add("item_number_" + i, donations[i].AccountName);
}
```

I was hoping I could use something like:

```
NameValueCollection nvc = new NameValueCollection();

List<BusinessLogic.Donation> donations = new List<BusinessLogic.Donation>();
donations.Add(new BusinessLogic.Donation(0, "", "", "");
donations.Add(new BusinessLogic.Donation(0, "", "", "");
donations.Add(new BusinessLogic.Donation(0, "", "", "");

donations.ForEach(x => nvc.Add("item_name_" + ??, x.AccountName);
```

But I've not found a way to determine which iteration the loop is on. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does donations have an .IndexOf() method?

Comment: You could do `int i = 0; donations.ForEach(x=> nvc.Add("item_name_" + i++, ...` but not sure how safe it is.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

LINQ doesn't have a `ForEach` method, and for good reason.  LINQ is for performing *queries*.  It is designed to get information from some data source.  It is *not* designed to mutate data sources.  LINQ queries shouldn't cause side effects, which is exactly what you're doing here.

The `List` class *does* have a `ForEach` method, which is what you are using.  Because it's not actually in the `System.Linq` namespace it's not technically a part of LINQ.

There is nothing wrong with the `for` loop in your question.  It would be wrong (from a good practice perspective) to try to change it in the way that you're trying to.

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx) is a link that discusses the matter in more detail.

Now, if you want to ignore that advice and use a `ForEach` method anyway, it's not hard to write one that provides an index to the action:

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, Action<int, T> action)
{
    // argument null checking omitted
    int i = 0;
    foreach (T item in sequence)
    {
        action(i, item);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I've obviously used the wrong terminology. My collection of `Donation` does have a `.ForEach()` method.

Comment: ForEach isn't defined as an extension method of IEnumerable<T> and therefore isn't part of LINQ.

Comment: @JamesHill It's a method of `List`.  It's not a method in `System.Linq`

Comment: @Servy, I think it's obvious that I need to step away from my computer for a while. I think coffee is in order. Thanks for setting me straight.

Comment: +1 for the link to that article. I've wondered why there wasn't a LINQ implementation of ForEach, but that makes perfect sense.

Comment: I like this, although you can drop the index computations and shorten up the code by replacing the implementation with just `foreach (var e in sequence.Select((item,n)=>(item,n))) action(e.n, e.item);`

Answer (score 28):

If you really want to use a List.ForEach, it's simple:

```
//[...]
int i=0;
donations.ForEach(x => nvc.Add("item_name_" + i++, x.AccountName);
```

Answer (score 16):

It's a little convoluted and creates an intermediate collection, but how about:

```
donations.Select((x, i) => new {Name = "item_name_" + i, x.AccountName})
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(x=> nvc.Add(x.Name, x.AccountName));
```

This uses [the overload of `Enumerable.Select` which incorporates the index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx).

I do have to argue there is nothing really to gain from doing it this way. You create more overhead with the intermediate collection and IMHO lose readability over your original for-loop.

You can also skip the intermediate collection if you're willing to use `foreach` loop instead of `List.ForEach`. See [@wageoghe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13055431/44853) (again highly recommended).

Answer (score 15):

This is an old post but is highly ranked by Google so I figured a more generic approach would be suitable. (Also, I tend to forget how this is done which means I have to google every time...)

Assume a list of integers:

`var values = new List<int>() { 2, 3, 4, 0x100, 74, 0xFFFF, 0x0F0F };`

To iterate the list and having an index do the following:

```
values.Select((x, i) => new
{
    item = x,
    index = i
})
.ToList()
.ForEach(obj =>
{
    int value = obj.item;
    int valueIndex = obj.index;
});
```

Comment: The downside to this is you lose lazy evaluation of `values`, as `ToList()` will force an enumeration over the entire source before `ForEach` is applied. E.g. see the difference in the output of the two methods [in this program](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Gikaox).

Comment: I'm not a developer, and sometimes I get mad when devs gives answers like "This is not how you should do it, because blah blah blah...." And I understand there's always a better way. But it's answers like yours that make me want to learn more about programming. Sometimes is not about the best way. Thank you!
List<sbyte> input; byte[] bytedata = new byte[input.Count]; input.Select((x, i) => new { item = x, index = i }).ToList().ForEach(o => bytedata[o.index] = (byte)o.item);

Comment: And tell you what, made a simple raw test, and your method was faster than using a for loop.

Answer (score 4):

Piggybacking on the answer by @lc.

```
foreach (var x in donations.Select((d, i) => new {ItemName = "item_name_" + i, AccountName = d.AccountName}))
{
  nvc.Add(x.ItemName, x.AccountName);
}
```

Comment: Now that tuples exist you can shorten up the `new{}` syntax a bit by using `(d, i) => ($"item_name_{i}", d.AccountName)` instead. Then either use `x.Item1` and `x.Item2`, or name the tuple fields instead of using `x`.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done using aggregate as well. Check the following example:

```
var data = new[]
{
    "A",
    "B",
    "C",
    "D"
};

var count = data.Aggregate(0, (index, item) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("[{0}] => '{1}'", index, item);

    return index + 1;
});

Console.WriteLine("Total items: {0}", count);
```

`Aggregate` here acts as a `for` statement. The only downside is that you need to increase the value of the index by one in each iteration and return it.

Answer (score 3):

Is there any reason you're not using a `Dictionary<string, string>` as your names/keys appear to be unique? This would be faster and you could use the `ToDictionary` standard query operator.

Also, if you did wish to use an extension method (although as Servy says a for loop is the right solution here), then you could write your own - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/521894/248164).

Answer (score 0):

I like to do that the following way:

```
NameValueCollection nvc = new NameValueCollection();

List<BusinessLogic.Donation> donations = new List<BusinessLogic.Donation>();
donations.Add(new BusinessLogic.Donation(0, "", "", ""));
donations.Add(new BusinessLogic.Donation(0, "", "", ""));
donations.Add(new BusinessLogic.Donation(0, "", "", ""));

Enumerable
    .Range(0, donations.Count())
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(i => nvc.Add("item_number_" + i, donations[i].AccountName));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this -

```
donations.ForEach(x =>
         {
             int index = donations.IndexOf(x);
             nvc.Add("item_name_" + index, x.AccountName);
         });
```

Comment: You're better off enumerating an intermediate collection with indices (a la @lc's answer) than searching the list on every iteration (`.IndexOf`)

Comment: What would happen if an item was in the list multiple times?  (Note that in the OP's code all of the items are identical.)  It's not *just* about the terrible performance after all; it doesn't even *work*.

Comment: So, is there any another way of finding index w/o creating an intermediate collection..?

Comment: @Sevy - Oops..!! Yeah it makes sense now to me. Just completely forget the uniqueness part. Downvotes accepted with honour now. :)

Comment: @RV1987 Sure.  Use a `for` loop like is done in the OP's code.  Or you could make a `ForEach` method that provides an index, like my answer shows, or you could create an integer `count` and increment it yourself in the loop.

Comment: @Sevy - Yeah thanks Servy got the point now..That's why i said atleast tell me where i am wrong.

Answer (score -2):

C# 7 (circa 2017) added a cleaner tuple syntax, which can be used with the indexed form of `Select` (there's no need to compute the index manually) to give a nice concise syntax. E.g.:

```
foreach ((var item, int n) in TheItems.Select((i,n)=>(i,n))) {
    // item is the current item, n is its index
}
```

Or if you prefer:

```
foreach (var element in TheItems.Select((item,n)=>(item,n))) {
    // element.item is the current item, element.n is its index
}
```

So in the OP's case, for example:

```
foreach ((var item, int n) in donations.Select((i,n)=>(i,n)))
    nvc.Add($"item_number{n}", item.AccountName);
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
foreach ((var k, var v) in donations.Select((i,n)=>($"item_number_{n}",i.AccountName)))
    nvc.Add(k, v);
```

Or, similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55020875/616460) but slightly less verbose, but note that this will kill lazy evaluation by calling `ToList()`, which forces enumeration over the whole source prior to calling `ForEach()`:

```
TheItems.Select((item,n)=>(item,n)).ToList().ForEach(element => { 
    // element.item is the current item, element.n is its index
});
```

Comment: *I feel like this solution already should have been here* -- Well, there are *several* answers based on this `Select` overload. What's new here?

Comment: @GertArnold foreach over Select, and not maintaining an index counter, and more concise code. Most of the answers "based on" Select do a bit of extra stuff or kill the lazy evaluation.

Comment: The only thing that matters here is the `Select` overload. You make it seem you're the first to mention it. Even then, there's really no need to add an endless number of varieties how to use it. In the mean time one might wonder why no one has yet simply created `nvc` from `donations` directly only using `Select` and `ToList` without `Foreach` or `foreach`. That would have been the least verbose solution. I don't feel any urge to add yet another answer though.

Comment: @GertArnold In the general sense (although a non-issue in the OP's case), using `ToList()` will force enumeration over the entire source series before proceeding. So if the source is some lazily produced IEnumerable, you'll lose the lazy evaluation there, which can be a problem in certain situations.

Comment: @GertArnold Re: Creating `nvc` directly, [an.dreas.k's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53429193) is pretty close, but there aren't really any methods to produce a `NameValueCollection` like that. `ToDictionary()` doesn't help (but [devdigital](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13054522)'s suggestion would make it possible), and while you could build an NVC with e.g. `Aggregate` or something, at that point you might as well just use `Add`. Also it's unclear if the OP intends to create a new NVC or add to an existing one, but from the question it looks slightly more like the latter.

Comment: @GertArnold Btw, there is only one other answer here that 1) doesn't explicitly compute the index, and 2) preserves lazy evaluation. My main point in this answer was more that tuples (which didn't exist in their current form when the older answers were posted) clean up the syntax even further. I do see what you mean about "You make it seem you're the first to mention [Select]"; I can reword that.

Answer (score -2):

I **strongly** recommend against this method, *unless you're trolling your friends*.

This is a way to create a "For" loop with Linq, but with MANY downsides:

```
int[] arr = new int[] {1, 1, 1, 1};

Enumerable.Range(0, arr.length)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(i => 
        {
            arr[i] += 2;
        });
```

The array should now be `{3, 3, 3, 3}`.

Again, *do not use this!*

Some of these downsides are (but not limited to):

- Really slow performance
- Large amount of memory usage
- Unreadable

Here's an example of how unreadable it can be:
[image: Unreadable example]

*I made this so my friend wouldn't mess with my code.*

The code creates a "for" loop that goes from 0.00 to 1.00 at an 0.01 increment and then "bakes"  the curve.

Comment: nice rube goldberg loop :-D

Answer (score -3):

A crappy solution would be to simply use select and return a useless value.

```
items.toList().Select((el, index) =>
{
    el.doStuff();
    return 0;
});
```

Comment: I just did this. Don't tell anybody, lol.

Comment: @JasonC Your secret is safe with me

Comment: This code has almost as many issues as words. It does nothing because the statement is not executed. And when spelling is corrected, `ToList` is redundant. The `Select` body  doesn't do anything with `index`. When executed, it would only return a list of zeros and (probably) change the source objects, which isn't asked. It won't add anything to `NameValueCollection nvc`. Crappy, sure.

Comment: @GertArnold its pseudo code to convey the concept. Not a pastable sample. If you're going to complain about spelling, you should know that sentences do not start with "And". `ToList` is not redundant since it implies that items was an standard type array that needed conversion. It doesn't need to do anything with index, its just showing that its available if you need it. `foreach` doesn't need to return anything in the first place so I don't know why you're whining about that.

Comment: Pseudo code isn't really useful in answers. Besides, there were already enough answers suggesting this overload of `Select`. And telling how to use it in real code.

Comment: @GertArnold Even if ToList were redundant, nobody would force you to not type it. Also, pseudo code is extremely useful in examples although, yes, you'd need a reasonably functional neural network with basic reasoning capabilities to apply the concept, which may or may not be an issue for you.

Comment: Also the key and unique point of this answer is using Select directly to execute the action. The unused return value is the whole point, it's the key part of this kludge. To use it in real code just ... use it in real code.

Comment: @GertArnold Here you go buddy, this one's for you: `Parallel.Invoke(new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1 }, Data.Select((e,n) => () => DoSomething(e,n)).ToArray());`, and it doesn't even waste any returned values. https://dotnetfiddle.net/chd5i7