# Output of helper within extension method being swallowed in Razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, razor-2

Following on from this question [foreach with index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521687/c-sharp-foreach-with-index) I have been trying to do something along the following lines:

Using an extension method:

```
    public static void Each<T>(this IEnumerable<T> ie, Action<T, int> action)
    {
        var i = 0;
        foreach (var e in ie) action(e, i++);
    }
```

Do an iteration in my view using the index, and outputting the result of a helper method.

```
            <div class="col-md-12">
                @{ 
                    Model.Take(5).Each((item, n) =>
                    {
                           @RenderItem(item, n == 3);
                    });
                }
           </div
```

With the following helper

```
@helper RenderItem(Item item, bool special = false)
{
      <p>Special rendeing for special items in here</p>
}
```

However the output is swallowed and not output. Is there a trick to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this extension method you are not sending anything to the view. The return value of `@RenderItem` is never sent to the view. Razor helpers are functions that simply return a `HelperResult` but you need to send this `HelperResult` to the view. When you invoke a helper using `@MyHelper` this renders the `HelperResult` because that is what the `@` does: render something.

But, when you are doing:

```
Model.Take(5).Each((item, n) =>
      {
           @RenderItem(item, n == 3);
      });
```

You are just calling your helper but **not** rendering anything to the screen (note the ending ;). In this case the @ is not the render operator, is just the "go to Razor" switch.
What probably you would like to render is the output of `.Each` but you can't because Each is a void method.

I played a little with your code, just to show you these concepts. First I changed your `Each` method to return an `IEnumerable<HelperResult>`:

```
    public static IEnumerable<HelperResult> Each<T>(this IEnumerable<T> ie, Func<T, HelperResult> action)
    {
        var i = 0;
        foreach (var e in ie) yield return action(e);
    }
```

When a method expects a `HelperResult` in code (as the `Func<T,HelperResult>`) you can pass a Razor expression on it, so in my view i can do:

```
 @Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Each(i => @RenderItem(i, i == 3))
```

This will invoke my `RenderItem` helper but the output is just the following (note that if you put a breakpoint in RenderItem the breakpoint won't hit due the lazy invocation of Linq, just add a .ToList() after the Each call to force evaluation):

```
WebApplication1.FOo+<Each>d__0`1[System.Int32]
```

(If you used .ToList() this will change to something like `System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult]`)

This is because Razor knows how to render a  `HelperResult` but not a `IEnumerable<HelperResult>` which is what we really have.

So... what we need to do? Yes, just iterate over the result (using a standard foreach) and displaying every result:

```
@{
    var x = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Each(i => @RenderItem(i, i == 3));
    foreach (var ix in x)
    {
        @ix
    }
}
```

That will work as expected, you now are rendering your HelperResult one by one.

Of course, this code is just to show how Razor templates work :)

Hope it helps.