# Get the column index in Foreach loop over datarow

Tags: c#

In below Foreach loop

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
   foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
   {
       var val=row[col].ToString()
       var index=??
   }
}
```

How to check if current column is last column ?

Comment: use a for loop or have an integer that you increase

Comment: `dt.Columns.IndexOf(col)`

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/521705/365102

Comment: `if (dt.Columns.IndexOf(dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().LastOrDefault()) == dt.Columns.IndexOf(col))
                    {
                        
                    }`

Comment: What do you want? The column index, as per your title, or a check for whether the current column is the last (as per your question)? The former case was answered by @Fabio, and the latter would be a combination of that and `dt.Columns.Count`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If i Understand you correctly , the thing you looking for is Ordinal

```
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
     {
       foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
         {
           var index = col.Ordinal+1; // Current column index
           if(index == dt.Columns.Count) // if column is last column in current row
              {
                your logice goes here
              }
          }
     }
```

It gives you current position of column item

check this [MSDN Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.ordinal(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this as well:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{         
     for(int i=0; i< dt.Columns.Count; i++)
     {
        var val=row[i].ToString()
        // here i will be the index
        // dt.Columns[i] will be the column
     }
}
```

If your requirement is to do something with last column[as mentioned in the question] means need not to go ahead with iteration, you can make use of the column index like this: `row[dt.Columns.Count-1]`

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void DataD() {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("Drug", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Patient", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

        // Here we add five DataRows.
        table.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "David", DateTime.Now);
        table.Rows.Add(50, "Enebrel", "Sam", DateTime.Now);
        table.Rows.Add(10, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", DateTime.Now);
        table.Rows.Add(21, "Combivent", "Janet", DateTime.Now);
        table.Rows.Add(100, "Dilantin", "Melanie", DateTime.Now);
        int count = table.Columns.Count;
        var lastColumn = table.Columns[count - 1];
        string columnname = lastColumn.ColumnName;
        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
            {
                var val = row[col].ToString();
                var index = table.Columns.IndexOf(col);
                if (columnname == col.ColumnName) {
                    // this is my last colums
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help you

```
var index,val;
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
 foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
   {
      index=dt.Columns.IndexOf(col);
      val=row[index].ToString();

    if (index == dt.Columns.Count-1)
        //your code here...
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here try this.

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
  {
   var index =0;
   foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
       {
        var val=row[col].ToString()

          index++;
          if(index == dt.Columns.Count)
            //true
       }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the following peace of code

```
int total=dt.Columns.Count;
int i=0;
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
   {
if(i==total-1)
```

{

}

```
i++;
    var val=row[col].ToString()
    var index=??
   }
```

}